# How to Insert table column values: month & day from column datetype

Tags: sql, oracle11g, concatenation, oracle-sqldeveloper, datepart

I'm using Oracle 11g Schema

I want to select the month and day from a date concatenate it and put it into a column.

The syntax I have here makes sense but its throwing an error of..

```
INSERT INTO OB_SELECT_LST12_SPG WED 
  VALUES (((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('RET_DATE', MM))||( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('RET_DATE', DD)));
```

"SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming that `RET_DATE` is supposed to be a date column, not a string, correct?  Is `RET_DATE` a column in `OB_SELECT_LST12_SPG`?  Or is it a column in a different table?

Comment: I don't know if your whole insert is well written, but the error is clear, you are missing several parenthesis. For example, it should be like this: `VALUES ( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('RET_DATE', MM)) || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('RET_DATE', DD)));`. This is the first step

Comment: try this - `((To_Char(To_Date('RET_DATE', MM)))||( To_Char(To_Date('RET_DATE', DD))))`

Comment: @JustinCave Yes the RET is a column in the OB_SELECT_LST12_SPG table.

Comment: @rs. sorry.. still getting an error.. "SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values"

Comment: your syntax is wrong, is RET_DATE varchar or date datatype?

Comment: Please add the result of `SELECT * FROM OB_SELECT_LST12_SPG WHERE 1=0` to your question.

Comment: @rs. I just looked and its a date type..

Comment: check my answer below and also @ben post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points first...

1. Your table name has a space in in
2. Your not enough columns error is caused by you having more than one column in the table
3. You really shouldn't be doing this at all
4. If `ret_date` is a column don't encapsulate it in quotation marks (`'`) as you won't be able to convert the string `'ret_date'` into a date.

However, assuming `ret_date` is a string that looks like `13-06-2012`

```
insert into ob_select_lst12_spg_wed (my_column)
values(to_char(to_date(:ret_date,'dd-mm-yyyy'),'mmdd'));
```

If `ret_date` is a date data-type then you can remove the inner conversion.

```
insert into ob_select_lst12_spg_wed (my_column)
values(to_char(:ret_date,'mmdd'));
```

`to_char` and `to_date` both make use of [datetime format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212), which have a number of options.

---

Please don't do this though. *Always store dates as dates*

---

From your comments `ret_date` is a date and the column `wed` is  a character. You're getting the error bind variable not declared because you haven't specified the variable. I'm going to assume that `ret_date` is in another table as it's a date, in which case lose the values key-word and insert directly from that table:

```
insert into ob_select_lst12_spg (wed)
select to_char(ret_date,'mmdd')
  from the_other_table
```

This shouldn't be required though, you can always convert a date into whatever you want on *exit* from the database. If you don't store it as a date in the database then it's easy for errors and incorrect values to creep in. I *personally* would change the column `wed` to a date, in which case your query becomes the very simple:

```
insert into ob_select_list12_spg (wed)
select ret_date
  from the_other_table
```

You can then use the correct [datetime format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) for your needs when selecting from the database.

Comment: The table column I am trying to add to is named WED. So, I have tried doing this.. insert into ob_select_lst12_spg (wed) values(to_char(:ret_date, 'mmdd')); and I get an error message telling me the bind variable "ret_date" is not declared.. is there something else I should be doing? So, if I hear you correctly.. I should be recreating that field wed as a date field instead of a varchar2 field?  I'll give that a try and see if that helps.. thanks for the explanation..

Comment: @BEN thanks.. I created a new column that is a date column. I only want the Month and day from the original date column.. Also, I was reading someplace else and found that the nls_date_format = dd-mon-rr. not sure how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing extra parentheses. Number of opened `(` was 8 and closed `)` was 5

```
INSERT INTO OB_SELECT_LST12_SPG(WED) 
VALUES ((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(RET_DATE, MM)))||( TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(RET_DATE, DD))));
```

**Update**
Make sure other columns are not required (i.e. Allow NULLs)

Comment: I don't know if this has something to do with it but the RET_DATE field is already a date type.. I tried your statement and it still throws the error "SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values"

Answer (score 0):

Sample query to get date, month from date column:

```
Select ((To_Char(to_date('01-FEB-73','dd-mon-yy'), 'MM'))
       ||( To_Char(to_date('01-JAN-73','dd-mon-yy'), 'dd')))
 from dual;
```

if RET_DATE is date datatype then use

```
insert into table_name (columname) 
Select ((To_Char(RET_DATE, 'MM'))
           ||( To_Char(RET_DATE, 'dd')))
     from dual;
```